# c# Show datagridview column's distinct value in combobox item

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, combobox

On runtime I am changing some columns of datagridview into combobox columns. Now how do I get the existing distinct values in the combobox items? I am using entity model as datasource. My code is:

```
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = null;
var context = new AdminEntities();
var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName)
                               .GetValue(context, null);
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Take(0);
var source = new BindingSource { DataSource = truncatedData };
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = source;
dgvLoadTable.ReadOnly = false;
dgvLoadTable.AllowUserToAddRows = true;

for (int row= 0; row < dgvLoadTable.Rows.Count; row++
{
  for (int col = 0; col < dgvLoadTable.Columns.Count; col++)
  {
    if (col == 2 || col == 4)
    {
      this.dgvLoadTable[col, row] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

      var item = dgvLoadTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                  .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value != null)
                                  .Select(r => r.Cells[col].Value)
                                  .Distinct();
      ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvLoadTable[col,row]).Items
                                                       .AddRange(item
                                                                .ToArray());
      dgvLoadTable[col, row].ValueType = typeof(var);
    }
  }
}                             
dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

But this is not working, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
dgvLoadTable[col, row].ValueType = typeof(var);
```

This is wrong. Please either leave it out or make it the type of the data, not its collection!  What data types are in columns 2 & 4?

for string or integer you could write

```
dgvLoadTable[col, row].ValueType = typeof(string);
```

or

```
dgvLoadTable[col, row].ValueType = typeof(int);
```

**But:** You probably don't need to control the datatype since it was generated with the column and you have onyl change the column type, not the value type.

**However** I found that the values need to be restored after changing the cells; so the whole piece of code ought to look like this:

```
  for (int row= 0; row < dgvLoadTable.Rows.Count; row++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < dgvLoadTable.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
      if (col == 2 || col == 4)
      {
        var temp = dgvLoadTable[col, row].Value;
        this.dgvLoadTable[col, row] = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        dgvLoadTable[col, row].Value = temp;

        var items = dgvLoadTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value != null)
                   .Where(r => r.Cells[col].Value != null)
                   .Select(r => r.Cells[col].Value)
                   .OrderBy(r => r).Distinct();

        ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dgvLoadTable[col, row])
                                   .Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());


       }
    }
 }                             
 dgvLoadTable.Refresh();
```

Other than that our code works fine, provided you have data in `item`.

It will contain all those distinct values, provided there are data in the column. I have added an optional sort and an additional where clause to make sure no null values creep in..

Please note the order of things: first we store the value, then change the cell, then restore the value and finally we fill the combobox items!

Comment: It throws exception that DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

Comment: Well, what data types are in the columns??

Comment: I fixed the exception but there is nothing showing up in combobox items. The data type is not fixed, it varies from column to column

Comment: put a breakpoint on `((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvLoadTable[col, row]).Items.AddRange(item.ToArray());` and look at `item`! Does it have data??

Comment: If necessary you should use the right valueType for those columns. We are only talking about #2 & #4!.. But maybe you can leave out setting the valuetype altogether!

Comment: item doesn't have any data, that's the problem. This line : var item = dgvLoadTable.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value != null).Select(r => r.Cells[col].Value).Distinct(); is wrong probably.

Comment: Actually the code for items looks ok, at least for my test data. You may want to look into the where clause and check on column 0.. Also please note the changed order..!!